# Move TextArea cursor on MouseArea click in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

There is a TextArea and i have set `activeFocusOnPress` porperty to `false` to block Virtual keyboard pop up, But when user clicks on the TextArea the cursor position should move. To achive this i thought mousearea will be good option. Following is the code:

```
TextArea{
    id:textArea
    text:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"    
    width:100
    height: 200
    color: "white"
    cursorVisible: true
    activeFocusOnPress: false //To Block virtual Keyboard popup

    background: Rectangle{
        color:"transparent"
        border.color : "white"
        border.width:2
        MouseArea{
            id:mousearea
            anchors.fill:parent
            onClicked: {

                //*** How to set cursor position??                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting [selectByMouse](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#selectByMouse-prop) to true, and leave out the mouse area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
textArea.cursorPosition = textArea.positionAt(mouseX, mouseY)
```